# React forwardRef meaning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I don't get what's the point of this:

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));
```

If i can do this:

```
function FancyButton(props) {
  return (
    <button className="FancyButton" ref={props.ref}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: you should **createRef** in parent component and link it in child using **forwardRef**

Answer (score 4):

From the documents

> Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through
>   a component to one of its children.
>
> Ref forwarding is an opt-in feature that lets some components take a
>   ref they receive, and pass it further down (in other words, “forward”
>   it) to a child.

For your question

> I don't get what's the point of this: If i can do this:.

You can either choose first approach or second approach

Example

```
// EmailInput wraps an HTML `input` and adds some app-specific styling.
const EmailInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <input ref={ref} {...props} type="email" className="AppEmailInput" />
));

class App extends Component {
  emailRef = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <EmailInput ref={this.emailRef} />
        <button onClick={() => this.onClickButton()}>
          Click me to focus email
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // `this.emailRef.current` points to the `input` component inside of EmailInput,
  // because EmailInput is forwarding its ref via the `React.forwardRef` callback.
  onClickButton() {
    this.emailRef.current.focus();
  }
}
```

To me the fowardRef is not need much because we can always pass ref using another approach

You can read more at [here](https://vijayt.com/post/react-forwardref-example-and-why-it-should-not-be-part-of-react-api/)

Comment: it seems to me the forwardRef is needed because there is no this.props.ref on react component only on some low level elements and also not on functional components. but i thought it worked until now.

Comment: @TonyNgo, that article was very informative, and exactly what I was looking for. It's funny how the official documentation makes NO MENTION of passing refs as normal props, but it sounds like it's actually an okay (if not better) practice than using forwardRef.