# Warning:React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by FormContent Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

i defined a selectinputField component, and i call it in my form, but i have an error saying:

**React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by FormContent**.

**My SelectInputField**

```
export const SelectCompanyField = () => {
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
const { data, error } = useSWR<ServerResponse, any>(companyUrls.base, url => getDataByParams(companyUrls.base));
console.log("Data", data, "Error", error);
console.log(data?.entities);


return (

    <Select

        showSearch
        placeholder="Choisir une compagnie"
        optionFilterProp="children"
        filterOption={(input, option: any) =>
            option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
    >
        {data?.entities.map(d => (
            <option value={d.index} key={d.id}  >
                {d.name}
            </option>
        ))}

    </Select>


);
```

};

**Part where there is an error in my form**

```
   {firstOptionValue && 
    <Col md={24} lg={24} sm={24}>
                    <div className="ant-form-item">
                        <label className="label">Compagnie <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <Controller
                            as={SelectCompanyField()}
                            name="company"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue={""}
                            rules={{ required: false }}
                        />
                        {errors.company && "Company is required"}
                    </div>
 </Col>
}
```

the column should appear if firstOptionValue is true. But when firstOptionValue is true I get the error mentioned above.

I tried an alternative, that of directly calling my select component with firstOptionValue, but when I submit my form, the value selected in the input of the select component, does not appear in my data after the submission, while the others appear.

**Alternative**

```
<Col md={24} lg={24} sm={24}>
          <div className="ant-form-item">
                 <label className="label">Compagnie <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
{firstOptionValue && <SelectCompanyField/>
                    
                        {errors.company && "Company is required"}
                    </div>

                </Col>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just pass the component, do not call it: `as={SelectCompanyField}`

Comment: How ? Where i must pass the component ?

Comment: I've quoted your own code, so, exactly where it is, assuming the `Controller` component expects a `ElementType`, which is either a component function or class, or a string for basic HTML tag names.

Comment: When i use ```as={SelectCompanyField}```, it's show me the warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. And my input has no value after submit

Comment: It means that the problem you had is fixed, but you're now facing [a new problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56751609/1218980).

Comment: When i try my alternative method, i have no error, but when I choose a value in my new input that appears, this value and his name does not appear in my data after submitting the form. I did like this: ```{firstOptionValue && <SelectCompanyField />}```

Comment: I'm sorry, but a question should focus on a single problem. Once that's fixed, if you're facing new issues, you need to go through the process again and, if necessary, open a new question with an up-to-date description and [mcve].